# Принт не выводит результаты. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я решаю задачку, и хочу вот посмотреть как она отрабатывает, но принт ничего не выводит. Пробовал просто через запятую joke склеивать и ide жаловалась. Сделал через формат: не жалуется, но не выводит.
**КОД И ЗАДАНИЕ:**

```
"""
5. Реализовать функцию get_jokes(), возвращающую n шуток, сформированных из трех случайных слов, взятых из трёх списков:
nouns = ["автомобиль", "лес", "огонь", "город", "дом"]
adverbs = ["сегодня", "вчера", "завтра", "позавчера", "ночью"]
adjectives = ["веселый", "яркий", "зеленый", "утопичный", "мягкий"]
        Например:
# >>> get_jokes(2)
["лес завтра зеленый", "город вчера веселый"]

Документировать код функции.
Сможете ли вы добавить еще один аргумент — флаг,
разрешающий или запрещающий повторы слов в шутках (когда каждое слово можно использовать только в одной шутке)?
Сможете ли вы сделать аргументы именованными?


"""
```

```
    from random import choice
    
    nouns = ["автомобиль", "лес", "огонь", "город", "дом"]
    adverbs = ["сегодня", "вчера", "завтра", "позавчера", "ночью"]
    adjectives = ["веселый", "яркий", "зеленый", "утопичный", "мягкий"]
    list_1 = []
    
    
    def get_jokes(n, flag = False):
        for i in range(n):
            random_index = choice(nouns)
            random_index_1 = choice(adverbs)
            random_index_2 = choice(adjectives)
            joke = "{} {} {}".format(random_index, random_index_1, random_index_2)
            print(joke)
            print(random_index)
            list_2 = []
            if flag == True:
                list_2 = joke.split()
                for i in range(len(nouns)):
                   for fun in list_2:
                       if nouns[i] == fun:
                           nouns.pop(i)
    
            print(nouns)
    
    get_jokes(3)
```

Можете помочь, почему результата нету и есть ли тут какие-то ошибки? Если будет желание, можете подсказать, как еще можно сделать всю эту тему с флагом, только не сложным путем, я новичек.

Comment: get_jokes(3, flag=True) не пробовали?

Comment: если так пишу, то выскакиевает такая ошибка: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\79257\Desktop\скрипты\Фавн_Августа_dz_3\проект_3\main.py", line 41, in <module>
    get_jokes(n=3, flag=True)
  File "C:\Users\79257\Desktop\скрипты\Фавн_Августа_dz_3\проект_3\main.py", line 36, in get_jokes
    if nouns[i] == fun:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range у вас же написано, что индекс больше размера листа. у вас nouns = 5, list_2 = 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_jokes(n, flag=False):
    jokes = []

    for _ in range(n):
        noun = choice(nouns)
        adverb = choice(adverbs)
        adjective = choice(adjectives)

        if flag:
            # или удаляйте выбранные слова из списка слов (плохой вариант, но если из копий, то - ок)
            # или создавайте списки использованных слов и проверяйте, не было ли еще такого (может быть медленно на коротких списках)
            # или составьте новую шутку и проверьте, нет ли ее в уже созданных (тоже может быть медленно)
            # или перемешайте копии исходных списков и берите слова поочередно (лучший, на мой взгляд, вариант)
            pass

        jokes.append(f'{noun} {adverb} {adjective}')

    return jokes
```

Я бы на вашем месте перепробовал бы всевозможные варианты уникализации;)

```
>>> print(get_jokes(3))
['город вчера яркий', 'дом сегодня утопичный', 'город ночью яркий']
```

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на дополнительный вопрос в комментариях, почему выходит ошибка:

```
for i in range(len(nouns)):
   for fun in list_2:
       if nouns[i] == fun:
           nouns.pop(i)
```

Вы итерируетесь по списку, при этом удаляя из него элементы. В конце-концов у вас `i` оказывается за пределами списка, потому что список стал размером меньше, чем `len(nouns)` из-за этих удалений.

Это можно починить, например, так:

```
for n in nouns.copy():
   for fun in list_2:
       if n == fun:
           nouns.remove(n)
```

Хотя по-хорошему это всё делается ещё проще с помощью вычитания множеств.

Answer (score 1):

Все сделано, вот без ошибок, спасибо всем кто помог:

```
from random import choice

nouns = ["автомобиль", "лес", "огонь", "город", "дом"]
adverbs = ["сегодня", "вчера", "завтра", "позавчера", "ночью"]
adjectives = ["веселый", "яркий", "зеленый", "утопичный", "мягкий"]
list_1 = []


def get_jokes(n, flag=False):
    for i in range(n):
        random_index = choice(nouns)
        random_index_1 = choice(adverbs)
        random_index_2 = choice(adjectives)
        joke = f'{random_index} {random_index_1} {random_index_2}'
        list_2 = []
        print(joke)
        if flag == True:
            list_2 = joke.split()
            for noun in nouns:
                for fun in list_2:
                    if noun == fun:
                        nouns.remove(noun)

            for adverb in adverbs:
                for fun in list_2:
                    if adverb == fun:
                        adverbs.remove(adverb)


            for adjective in adjectives:
                for fun in list_2:
                    if adjective == fun:
                        adjectives.remove(adjective)




get_jokes(n=3, flag=True)
```